# Where to store sensitive data on IBM i machine

Tags: ibm-midrange

I want to store sensitive data on IBMi machine.
Anyone know any secured location on IBMi machine where I can store sensitive data like key which is used for encryption.

Comment: Any location with the appropriate security set? What is your real question?

Comment: Have you read up on security in the [Knowledge Center?](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzahg/welcome.htm)

Comment: @jmarkmurphy Location where i can store the encryption key. I want to store it in secured location having restricted access.

Comment: Create the appropriate secured location with secured access. How you do that is in the Knowledge Center. Anywhere on the disk can be secure or not depending on the security plan you set up. No one can give you this information because no one knows your security plan. To provide you with a security plan is a lot of work. Way more than is appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Store in memory and dis-guard when finished.  Same as any other computer system.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use [Cryptographic services key management](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzajc/rzajckeymgmt.htm)

> Cryptographic services key management for the IBM® i operating system allows you to store and manage master keys and keystores. Since you are exchanging sensitive data to manage master keys and keystores, it is recommended that you use a secure session.
>
> Cryptographic Services supports a hierarchical key system. At the top of the hierarchy is a set of master keys. These keys are the only key values stored in the clear (unencrypted). Cryptographic services securely stores the master keys within the IBM i Licensed Internal Code (LIC).